# Gtk+: How to align a label to the left in a table

Tags: c, gtk

I'm currently playing a little bit with the gtk library, and trying to create a simple window application using C, but I'm having some difficult time aligning labels in a table.

To be more specific, this is what I've written so far:

```
#include<gtk/gtk.h>


static void dest(GtkWidget*, gpointer);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    GtkWidget *window;
    GtkWidget *table;
    GtkWidget *label1, *folderChooser1;
    GtkWidget *label2, *folderChooser2;

    gtk_init(&argc,&argv);


    /*************************************
     * setting the first row in table
     *************************************/
    label1=gtk_label_new("Browse For a Folder To Backup: ");
    //gtk_misc_set_alignment(GTK_MISC(label1), 0, .5);              // neither this
    //gtk_label_set_justify(GTK_LABEL(label1, GTK_JUSTIFY_LEFT);    // nor this aligns the label to the left.
    folderChooser1=gtk_file_chooser_button_new("Browse For Folder...", GTK_FILE_CHOOSER_ACTION_SELECT_FOLDER);
    gtk_file_chooser_set_current_folder(GTK_FILE_CHOOSER (folderChooser1), g_get_home_dir());


    /*************************************
     * setting the second row
     *************************************/
    label2=gtk_label_new("Choose Backup Path: ");
    //gtk_misc_set_alignment(GTK_MISC(label2), 0, .5);              // neither this
    //gtk_label_set_justify(GTK_LABEL(label2, GTK_JUSTIFY_LEFT);    // nor this aligns the label to the left.
    folderChooser2=gtk_file_chooser_button_new("Browse For Folder...", GTK_FILE_CHOOSER_ACTION_SELECT_FOLDER);
    gtk_file_chooser_set_current_folder(GTK_FILE_CHOOSER (folderChooser2), g_get_home_dir());


    /***************************************
     * setting table
     ***************************************/
    table=gtk_table_new(2,2,TRUE);
    gtk_table_attach(GTK_TABLE(table), label1, 0, 1, 0, 1, GTK_SHRINK, GTK_SHRINK, 15, 0);
    gtk_table_attach(GTK_TABLE(table), label2, 0, 1, 1, 2, GTK_SHRINK, GTK_SHRINK, 15, 0);
    gtk_table_attach_defaults(GTK_TABLE(table), folderChooser1, 1, 2, 0, 1);
    gtk_table_attach_defaults(GTK_TABLE(table), folderChooser2, 1, 2, 1, 2);


    /********************************
     * setting window 
     ********************************/
    window=gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window), "Backup");
    gtk_window_set_resizable(GTK_WINDOW(window), FALSE);
    gtk_container_set_border_width(GTK_CONTAINER(window), 10);

    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(window), "destroy", G_CALLBACK(dest), NULL);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER (window), table);   

    gtk_widget_show_all(window);

    gtk_main();
    return 0;
}


static void dest(GtkWidget *window, gpointer data) {
    gtk_main_quit();
}
```

The above code will produce this:

[image]

As you can see, the labels are centred, where I want it to be left-alinged. 
None of the commented-out lines worked for me.
Is there even a way to align labels inside table cells'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gtk_misc_set_alignment` works for me as long as I also use `gtk_table_attach_defaults` to attach the labels:

Full code for reference:

```
#include<gtk/gtk.h>


static void dest(GtkWidget*, gpointer);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    GtkWidget *window;
    GtkWidget *table;
    GtkWidget *label1, *folderChooser1;
    GtkWidget *label2, *folderChooser2;

    gtk_init(&argc,&argv);


    /*************************************
     * setting the first row in table
     *************************************/
    label1=gtk_label_new("Browse For a Folder To Backup: ");
    gtk_misc_set_alignment(GTK_MISC(label1), 0, .5);              // neither this
    //gtk_label_set_justify(GTK_LABEL(label1, GTK_JUSTIFY_LEFT);    // nor this aligns the label to the left.
    folderChooser1=gtk_file_chooser_button_new("Browse For Folder...", GTK_FILE_CHOOSER_ACTION_SELECT_FOLDER);
    gtk_file_chooser_set_current_folder(GTK_FILE_CHOOSER (folderChooser1), g_get_home_dir());


    /*************************************
     * setting the second row
     *************************************/
    label2=gtk_label_new("Choose Backup Path: ");
    gtk_misc_set_alignment(GTK_MISC(label2), 0, .5);              // neither this
    //gtk_label_set_justify(GTK_LABEL(label2, GTK_JUSTIFY_LEFT);    // nor this aligns the label to the left.
    folderChooser2=gtk_file_chooser_button_new("Browse For Folder...", GTK_FILE_CHOOSER_ACTION_SELECT_FOLDER);
    gtk_file_chooser_set_current_folder(GTK_FILE_CHOOSER (folderChooser2), g_get_home_dir());


    /***************************************
     * setting table
     ***************************************/

    table=gtk_table_new(2,2,TRUE);
    //gtk_table_attach(GTK_TABLE(table), label1, 0, 1, 0, 1, GTK_SHRINK, GTK_SHRINK, 15, 0);
    //gtk_table_attach(GTK_TABLE(table), label2, 0, 1, 1, 2, GTK_SHRINK, GTK_SHRINK, 15, 0);
    gtk_table_attach_defaults(GTK_TABLE(table), label1, 0, 1, 0, 1);
    gtk_table_attach_defaults(GTK_TABLE(table), label2, 0, 1, 1, 2);
    gtk_table_attach_defaults(GTK_TABLE(table), folderChooser1, 1, 2, 0, 1);
    gtk_table_attach_defaults(GTK_TABLE(table), folderChooser2, 1, 2, 1, 2);

    /********************************
     * setting window
     ********************************/
    window=gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window), "Backup");
    gtk_window_set_resizable(GTK_WINDOW(window), FALSE);
    gtk_container_set_border_width(GTK_CONTAINER(window), 10);

    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(window), "destroy", G_CALLBACK(dest), NULL);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER (window), table);

    gtk_widget_show_all(window);

    gtk_main();
    return 0;
}


static void dest(GtkWidget *window, gpointer data) {
    gtk_main_quit();
}
```

(tested with gtk 2.0 on Ubuntu 12.04)

Comment: Yup! same here... :)  Thank you.
Why does the non-default version prevent the alignment?

Comment: I don't know, but I do notice that as long as I call `gtk_table_attach` with `GTK_FILL` among the `xoptions` parameter it works fine